# Max number of values in report paramter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am using SSRS 2012 to create reports, I am going to use report parameter with multiple values allowed.

I want to know what's the limit of report parameters **values** as it doesn't say anything here,

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337396(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @AndreyMorozov that is for SSRS 2005 and this is for SSRS 2012, how can they be same without blind assumption ?

Comment: @AndreyMorozov Also according to SO rules that question should be closed as it doesn't has any accepted answer not this...

Comment: @AndreyMorozov even though I know what you said is wrong, but can you provide me a reference for what you stated please ? thanks

Comment: ok ok, it's a very good question (+1) for all people who do not know how to use google